# how do you do find out what domain an ip address is associated with?

Tags: dns, reverse-dns

When I do:

```
ping www.google.com
```

it comes back with a response

```
PING www.google.com (172.253.122.147): 56 data bytes
```

So this means [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) resolves to 172.253.122.147.

What command(s) can I run to determine the reverse (i.e. given 172.253.122.147, it spits out [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) ) ?

Comment: It means that is _one_ of the _many_ v4 addresses www.google.com resolves to (for one of google's many servers at many datacenters around the world). See https://dnschecker.org/#A/www.google.com and https://dnschecker.org/#AAAA/www.google.com for a sampling of the others, but remember they change frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What command(s) can I run to determine the reverse (i.e. given 172.253.122.147, it spits out [www.google.com](http://www.google.com))

Normally you would use [Nslookup - Name server lookup - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/nslookup.html), but in this case the answer is not what you are looking for:

```
F:\test>nslookup 172.253.122.147
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.249.155

Name:    bh-in-f147.1e100.net
Address:  172.253.122.147
```

`bh-in-f147.1e100.net` is a name server and does not have a website associated with it. It belongs to Google:

```
Hostname                Type TTL Priority Content
bh-in-f147.1e100.net    SOA  60           ns1.google.com dns-admin@google.com 54750970 900 900 1800 60
bh-in-f147.1e100.net    A    3600         172.253.122.147
bh-in-f147.1e100.net    AAAA 3600         2607:f8b0:4004:c09::93
```

You can also try`whois`. There is an online version at [WHOIS Search, Domain Name, Website, and IP Tools - Who.is](https://who.is/) which tells you that this address belongs to Google:

```
NetRange:       172.253.0.0 - 172.253.255.255
CIDR:           172.253.0.0/16
NetName:        GOOGLE
NetHandle:      NET-172-253-0-0-1
Parent:         NET172 (NET-172-0-0-0-0)
NetType:        Direct Allocation
OriginAS:       AS15169
Organization:   Google LLC (GOGL)
RegDate:        2013-04-04
Updated:        2013-04-04
Ref:            https://rdap.arin.net/registry/ip/172.253.0.0
```

Comment: bh-in-f147.1e100.net/172.253.122.147 is not a name server; it does not respond on UDP/TCP53. It _is_ a webserver, one of (very) many at google, although it doesn't have _content_ for that name; `curl http://172.253.122.147` responds with an appropriate redirect and `curl http://bh-in-f147.1e100.net` (because of the different Host: header) with a 404. (In this case you could bypass whois by knowing that 1e100 is 10<sup>100</sup>, the mathematical 'googol' that google is named after.)